# TSQL - LAST_VALUE FUNCTION error (in SQL Server Management Studio 2012 )

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, ssms

I'm using SQL Server Management Studio 2012 and keep getting this error when I try to use functions like Last_value, Lag, etc.

What's odd is these functions are identified as I type them out, and the parameters are even highlighted in the hover text. But when I run it, I get this error.

> Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 23
>   'LAST_VALUE' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Is there something I don't know about what's going on with this function in express?? Please help.

My code is:
`SELECT LAST_VALUE([PERIOD VALUE]) OVER (PARTITION BY DEPARTMENT ORDER BY PERIOD)`
`FROM Table1`

Again, I'm using SQL Server Management Studio 2012 to access the database.

> Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio    11.0.2100.60
>   Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC) 6.1.7601.17514
>   Microsoft MSXML         3.0 5.0 6.0 
>   Microsoft Internet Explorer     9.0.8112.16421
>   Microsoft .NET Framework        4.0.30319.233
>   Operating System            6.1.7601

Comment: Are you using SQL Server 2012?

Comment: I know I'm using SQL Server Management Studio 2012. Can it be possible to use that on a Server that isnt SQL Server 2012? I genuinely don't know. How can I find out?

Comment: Try running `select @@VERSION` in a query window.

Comment: Ohhhhh this was really helpful guys, thanks. Turns out on the server side, we're on SQL Server 2008 so makes sense this isnt working. Thanks again xx

Answer (score 1):

select @@VERSION

revealed I was running 2008. I didn't realize my client application version differed from the server side.

Damien_The_Unbeliever, thanks for the tip.